# How can I extract certain content from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have certain URLs, for example:

```
http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/vistaras-turbulent-takeoffthe-cut-throat-indian-skies_3510081.html
http://www.business-standard.com/article/markets/patanjali-ayurved-targets-250-revenue-growth-in-fy16-edelweiss-115100900788_1.html
```

These can be any website URL. How can I extract `www.moneycontrol.com` or `www.business-standard.com` from the content?

Comment: Have a look at https://gist.github.com/acdcjunior/9820040 : `var myDomain = new ParsedUrl("http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/vistaras-turbulent-takeoffthe-cut-throat-indian-skies_3510081.html").host;`

Comment: Here is a version not using split: `var domains = urls.map(function(url) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href=url;
  return a.hostname;
});`

Answer (score 1):

You basically need the domain from the url. You can get it this way:

```
function extractDomain(url) {
    var domain;

    if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) 
        domain = url.split('/')[2];
    else 
        domain = url.split('/')[0];

    return domain.split(':')[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with two `split` functions to split a string into an array.

```
var path = string.split("://")[1].split('/')[0]
```

this gives you a URL like www.moneypath.com.

If you want to get just the url name, by eliminating `www.` and `.com`, either of these 2 will work.

```
path.replace(/(www.)|(.com)/g, '')
```

You can also use the split approach again

```
path.split('www.')[1].split('.com')[0]
```

Personally, I prefer the Regex approach since it's a little cleaner.

Comment: If you dont mind is it possible to eliminate www. and .com also ??

Comment: Sure, take a look at my answer